# AWS SES Email not showing attachments

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a bash script that creates a temporary directory, adds files to tmpDir, zips this in a new directory, and then sends that zip using amazon SES

I'm able to download the zip & see the attachment files on my device, but they are not visible on gmail- or one a windows device...

Is this an issue with the amazon SES configuration or with using a tmpDirectory?

```
tmpSizeDir=`mktemp -d`/
trap "rm -rf $tmpSizeDir" EXIT
#copying files into tmpSizeDir
zip folder.zip "${tmpSizeDir}"/*

  echo '{"Data": "From: '${MAIL_ACCOUNT}'\nTo: '${recipient}'\nSubject: '${MAIL_SUBJECT}'\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n'${MAIL_BODY}'\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: application/zip;\nContent-Disposition: attachment;\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64; filename=\"folder.zip\"\n\n'$(base64 folder.zip)'\n--NextPart--"}' > message.json

aws ses send-raw-email --raw-message file://message.json
```

Comment: What is in your zip file does it contain files gmail may block?   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

Comment: @RobertLove hmm it has a zip within a zip, which its seems gmail doesn't allow, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Gmail.   According to [Googles Documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590#zippy=%2Cmessages-that-have-attachments) only specific files are allowed to be attached.

Currently that includes:

> Certain types of files, including their compressed form (like .gz or
> .bz2 files) or when found within archives (like .zip or .tgz files)
> Documents with malicious macros Password-protected archives with
> archived content
>
> File types you can't include as attachments To protect your account,
> Gmail doesn't allow you to attach certain types of files. Gmail often
> updates the types of files not allowed to keep up with harmful
> software that is constantly changing.
>
> File types blocked by Gmail are:
>
> .ade, .adp, .apk, .appx, .appxbundle, .bat, .cab, .chm, .cmd, .com,
> .cpl, .diagcab, .diagcfg, .diagpack, .dll, .dmg, .ex, .ex_, .exe,
> .hta, .img, .ins, .iso, .isp, .jar, .jnlp, .js, .jse, .lib, .lnk,
> .mde, .msc, .msi, .msix, .msixbundle, .msp, .mst, .nsh, .pif, .ps1,
> .scr, .sct, .shb, .sys, .vb, .vbe, .vbs, .vhd, .vxd, .wsc, .wsf, .wsh,
> .xll